# Don't save the user when editing a list in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to make SharePoint not store the user name in the fields Created_at and Modified_by when editing a list. I want to make this completely anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get away without having the Created or Modified fields. I would suggest using an Event Receiver that changes the values to something safe (perhaps even System Account) on ItemAdded and ItemUpdated.

For more information, see:

- [SharePoint/WSS: Modify “created by” field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014215/sharepoint-wss-modify-created-by-field)
- [Changing “Created By” in Sharepoint 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383376/changing-created-by-in-sharepoint-2007)
- [SharePoint Documents Library - Change “Document Created By” field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919652/sharepoint-documents-library-change-document-created-by-field)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a SharePoint survey. In surveys can hide user names.